# How to overlap a point cloud file with another plot in Matlab?

Tags: matlab, image-processing, point-clouds

I have a `.pcd` file of a terrain survey that I opened using this command:

```
% read point cloud
big_island_cloud = pcread('C:\Users\to\path\Desktop\big_island_5m.pcd');
pcshow(big_island_cloud)
```

[image: surv]

Now I read from a `.csv` file all necessary columns using `readtable` in the following way and and verify that everything is fine `file(1:3,:)` and plot the result using `stackedplot`:

[image: table]

```
file = readtable('C:\Users\to\path\Desktop\EKF_USBL_CAM_Pose_Projected.csv');
file(1:3,:)
timeStamp = file(:,1);
pose_pose_position_x = file(:,4);
pose_pose_position_y = file(:,5);
stackedplot(file,{'time','field_pose_pose_position_x'});
```

and the following is what I obtain, `pose_pose_position_x` is going to be the trajectory I have to draw on top of the `.pcd` file:

[image: drawing]

How do I obtain the following output?:

[image: output]

Thank you for shedding light on this matter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Supposing that you have `[x,y,z]` for the data of your trajectories then you can simply superpose a plot with the use of `hold on` and `plot3`:

Based on the [example in the MATLAB documentation](https://www.mathworks.com/help/vision/ref/pcshow.html#buslb5n-10) :

```matlab
numFaces = 600;
[x,y,z] = sphere(numFaces);
figure;
pcshow([x(:),y(:),z(:)]);hold on % keeps the first plot on screen
plot3([1,1,-1],[1,0.5,1],[1,-0.5,-1]) % adds the trajectory on the plot
title('Sphere with Default Color Map');
xlabel('X');
ylabel('Y');
zlabel('Z');
```

#### Result

[image]

#### Edit

If you only have `[x,y]` then `plot` will replace `plot3`

```matlab
plot([1,1,-1],[1,0.5,1]) % adds the trajectory on the plot
```

Note that the trajectory will be drawn on the plane with `z=0`